# SSIS - remove character X unless it's followed by character Y

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Let's say I have the following dataset imported from a textfile:

```
Data
--------------------
1,"John Davis","Germany"
2,"Mike Johnson","Texas, USA"
3,"Bill "The man" Taylor","France"
```

I am looking for a way to remove every `"` in the data, unless it's followed or preceded by a `,`.

So in my case, the data should become:

```
Data
--------------------
1,"John Davis","Germany"
2,"Mike Johnson","Texas, USA"
3,"Bill The man Taylor","France"
```

I tried it with the import tekst file component in SSIS, but that gives an error when I set the column delimiter to `"`. If I don't set a delimiter, it sees the comma in "Texas, USA" as a split delimiter....

Any suggestions/ideas? The textfile is too large to change this manually for every line so that's not an option.

Comment: Replace all "," to | (Pipe or whatever).  Then you can remove all " in the file and  use that | as column delimiter .

Comment: Copy the data in Excel. Use `text to column` and choose comma separated delimit. Then you can easily replace unnecessary `"` by replacing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit of a cop-out on the last '"', but:

```
Create table #test ([Data] nvarchar(max))

insert into #test values ('1,"John Davis","Germany"'            )
insert into #test values ('2,"Mike Johnson","Texas, USA"'       )
insert into #test values ('3,"Bill "The man" Taylor","France"')

select replace(replace(replace(replace([Data],',"',',~'), '",','~,'),'"', ''),'~','"') + '"'
from #test
```