# SSIS - remove character when it has alphabetic character infront en behind it

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Let's say I have data imported from a csv in SSIS that looks like this:

```
ID,Name,Year,Place
1,"John",1994,"UK"
2,"Bill",1899,"USA"
3,"Gill",1989,"Germ"any"
```

In this case, there is a typo in `Germany`

I was wondering if there was a way (in derived column component maybe) to remove the `"` When the text is like `_"_`

_ being an alphabetic character or space.

This question came close to what I needed: [SSIS - remove character X unless it's followed by character Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787101/ssis-remove-character-x-unless-its-followed-by-character-y) , but it's done in SQL, while my data is in SSIS from a csv.

Comment: The wayward `"` is going to break the validity of the CSV. if you're using a double quote (`"`) as the text identifier and it can appear in your data you need to use a different text identifier.

Comment: @DenStudent: Only by SSIS you want to do? If so then there has inbuilt functionality for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that @Sami posted is a good option, and if you are specifically aiming to use a derived column for this then the following expression will remove any `"` while still keeping the leading and trailing double quotes.  Make sure to escape the `"` with a `\` character, otherwise the SSIS expression will fail.

```
"\"" + REPLACE(Place,"\"","") + "\""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([ID] int, [Name] varchar(45), [Year] int, [Place] varchar(45));

INSERT INTO T
    ([ID], [Name], [Year], [Place])
VALUES
    (1, '"John"', 1994, '"UK"'),
    (2, '"Bill"', 1899, '"USA"'),
    (3, '"Gill"', 1989, '"Germ"an"y"');

SELECT ID,
       Name,
       [Year],
       CONCAT('"', REPLACE(Place, '"', ''), '"') Place
FROM T;
```

**Returns:**

```
+----+--------+------+-----------+
| ID |  Name  | Year |   Place   |
+----+--------+------+-----------+
|  1 | "John" | 1994 | "UK"      |
|  2 | "Bill" | 1899 | "USA"     |
|  3 | "Gill" | 1989 | "Germany" |
+----+--------+------+-----------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=842f771dc4ae9bd7acb8a6979efe1838)**